# oracle duplicate columns to comma seperated string

Tags: oracle, group-by

I have duplicated columns in my table I think I should go with group by to get single instance but need a value in another column of that duplicated record
for exp:

```
username colour age
erick    blue    20
erick    red     20
dennis   green   24
```

I need a query give result like that; (return 2 rows)

```
username colour     age
erick    blue,red   20
dennis   green      24
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT username 
  ,LISTAGG(colour , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY colour ) AS colour 
  ,age
  FROM   t
  GROUP  BY
  username,age ;
```